# React.js: avoid delay on element <input type=“file”> onChange event

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, spfx-webparts, office-ui-fabric-react, reactjs

Any react-specific solution to the problem, described here?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46072489/how-to-avoid-delay-on-element-input-type-file-onchange-event?noredirect=1&lq=1

Basically the event fires with several seconds delay, so the behavior is the same as the one, described in the link: my onChange function shows a loader once the onChange method is entered but for several seconds the UI acts like nothing is happening at this moment.

Answer (score 0):

You may need share how you did as I can't reproduce.

```
handleChange(selectorFiles: FileList)
  {
      alert(selectorFiles);
  }
  public render(): React.ReactElement<ITestSpFxProps> {
    var modalStyles = {overlay: {zIndex: 9999}};
    return (
      <div className={ styles.testSpFx }>
        <div className={ this.GetCss(this.props.CSSOption) }>
          {this.props.CSSOption}
          <div className={ styles.row }>

          <button onClick={this.openModal}>Open Modal</button>
          <input type="file" onChange={ (e) => this.handleChange(e.target.files) } />
```

Comment: have you tried with a big file? (e.g. >200mb)